# set.seed() function - What is the best value for setting a seed?

Tags: r, random, random-seed

I was wondering if a certain seed value was better for a norm dist sample of data as opposed to a set that is skewed.  I understand that using the same seed on the same data will get you the same randomly generated records, I just wonder if seed 1-10 was better a neg skewed data range and 90-100 was better on a positive skew.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The only real benefit of a seed is that your results are reproducible. Ranges of seeds (at least as far as I know) aren't likely to be skewed in one direction more than any other, they just provide a concrete seed for the pseudo random generator rather than to use some entropy in the system.

Comment: thanks mate.  Should have thank you almost a year ago.  Apologies.